# Is there a way to update Server about the SSLHandshake exception from client?

Tags: java, cxf, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

Here is my situation. I have two hosts HostA and HostB. We trigger a workflow on HostA. HostA passes on this workflow to HostB to actually work on it. Now a workflow consists of 5 jobs. After a job is done HostB has to inform HostA that one job from the workflow is done. To pass on this information HostB acts as a client and validates HostA certificates and for all genuine reason throws' exception while validating. This leads to failure in SSLHandshake. As a result, the workflow status in HostA is hung in progress state for ever, as HostB is unable to reach HostA.
HostB has a Java-based implementation. We create our rest client (apache.cxf) and add a TLS validator to it. We have our own custom implementation of this validator.

What I wanted to know is that is there any way or design which addresses this issue. I do not want communication to happen when the certificate validation has failed, but I do want the server(in this case HostA) to be informed that SSLHandshake failure has happened.

As of now, the only solution I can think of is to catch the exception in the method which is trying to reach HostA, check if it is SSLHandshakeException and then propagate the error till server with a rest client which do not validate the certificate.

If there is any other better solution to it, I would like to know.
Thanks for the time to go through the content.

Comment: No, fortunately, you can't update server configuration from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could expose just a little thing over http or use socket and another port

I was consuming a site, which changed certificates continuously, a lot of ssl exceptions periodically ...
We scheduled a job that every day validated the url with the certificate store, and if it failed, the store was updated with the new certificate (sh + curl + openssl)